# Which is faster and performant: useState or useReducer?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

As I have seen in the doc, `useState` and `useReducer` does the same job.
Just `useReducer` need something to be done manually and is better for complex state.

My Question is, which is **faster**? I mean which will done a job in a less time?

Currently I am using `useState`:

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState({});

const setMessage = (message, room) => {
        setMessages(messages => {
          if (messages[room] !== undefined)
            return {...messages, [room]: [message, ...messages[room]] };
          else return { ...messages, [room]: [message] };
        });
}
```

Here as you can see I store messages of every room with setMessages.
This works very well, but I am confusing will it be **faster** if I use `useReducer` instead of `useState` ?

my message object is as below:

```
const message = {
      id: 'randomid',
      text: 'a message text',
      date: new Date(),
      user: 'user1',
      sent: false,
      received: false,
      delevered: false
}

const room = 'somerandomeroomid';
```

Comment: If you want to know which is faster, write a test to compare them based on your specific circumstances and use.

Comment: if it is a simple state then use useState

Comment: @KenWhite thank you, there is no circumestances as you can see, all job is just `setMessage` which appends all rooms messages.

I asked because here may in one second I retreive more than 50 messages so I want a faster function to store messages accurately.

Comment: That should make it very easy for you to write a test using both methods to see which is more perfomant, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useState` is using `useReducer` under the hood ([React source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/cef47cbc01b3c41ef4bfe3cdf7abd09c34e4a9c2/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L837)) :

```
function updateState<S>(initialState: (() => S) | S,): [S, Dispatch<BasicStateAction<S>>] {

  return updateReducer(basicStateReducer, (initialState: any));
}
```

I don't think there would be any performance difference at all.

Comment: if I use useReducer. for any re-rendering will it be called?
if it calls so it may affect on performance.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment. `useState` calls `useReducer`. It's just a function call, and should not have any effect on performance.

Answer (score 3):

As Mohamed Ramrami said -

> useState is using useReducer under the hood

so theoretically useReducer is faster whatsoever remember that

`Premature optimization is the root of all evil`

so focus on code quality and readability and you should solve perf issue using some measuring technique the moment you will start encountering them that might not even happen, React is pretty optimised.